# Deploying vue returns unexpted token < after build

Tags: vue.js, deployment, build, webdeploy

I have had no problems with deploying my vue projects so far and uploading it to my website. However suddenly Im getting the following errormessage after I have been running

```
npm run build
```

and uploading the files in my distfolder.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  chunk-vendors.468a5298.js:1
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
> '<'   app.f775d578.js:1

The only difference I can notice is that vue now seems to recommend using yarn.

I made a new project just for testing using yarn but with the same error.

1. vue create my-application
2. yarn install
3. yarn serve
4. yarn build

uploading content in distfolder to my website - same errormessage

Anyone else experienced this?

My old build works without any problems

Im using @vue/cli 4.5.6

I got it working now. Deleted the folder on my ftp and created a new one. Dont know this solved it but it did :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying your `dist` not to your root of the web, then one possible cause of this is an incorrect static assets path. Make sure both your css and js generated from `npm run build` are imported to the correct path from your web server

On `dist/index.html`, you will see something like this

```html
<link href=/js/chunk-....js rel=prefetch>
```

This means that it's an absolute path (root of the web), when it's supposed to be relative from the `dist` folder like this:

```html
<link href=js/chunk-....js rel=prefetch>
```

To easily fix this is, add `publicPath key` in your `vue.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  publicPath: ""
};
```

Then rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks. I however already have got this in my config file:
`module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/myurl/",
};`